# How can I set a bug to "Invalid"

Tags: tfs

With TFS, bugs can be either Active or Resolved.

So what happens if a bug is invalid - i.e. there is no bug to begin with.

How can I indicate that the bug was closed but no work was performed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mark it as Resolved and change the Reason field to whatever is appropriate.

[image]
<sub>(source: [pedautreppe.com](http://www.pedautreppe.com/image.axd?picture=2011%2F4%2FBug+Resolution+Status.jpg))</sub>